# Undelete these self deleted posts

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions

As continuation of following post:
[How do moderators deal with good questions, which are self deleted by the Original Poster (OP)?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/1049)

I am starting this thread. If you come across a **good Qn or a good answer**, which was self deleted by the author then **cast your vote for undeletion**. This is a good way, where the community itself can handle such petty issues.

Even if your flag is rejected for undeletion, put an answer with a link here.

**Side benefit**: Flags for deleted Qn-s are sensitively handled by Mods and hence they may reject it as well, if they don't find strong proof of impulsive behaviour. In between many of my undeletion flags were rejected & due to it I was banned from flagging anymore for several days. One may avoid such situation, by trying to resolve it here.

**Hint**: Find your own recently deleted answers from below URL:

> https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/{own user id}

Comment: It shows up in the [moderator tools](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tools) which needs delete vote/undelete. A meta post for undeletion of a post is same as close this question or reopen this question when the question is still in the review queue. If they are not undeleted after a very long time, we can ping the mods or users with delete privilege in chat rooms. A meta post is not needed in my opinion.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, last 3 of my flags were rejected for undeletion. One of the Qn-s was quite old. Posting a link to Qn in chatroom doesn't work out as effectively (even then I tried today). More people visit meta than chatrooms. We have so many Qn-s on meta, at least this is among, those which serves some purpose.

Answer (score 2):

- Answered by a user: [Do non-advaita vedanta philosophies also believe that buddhi is part of prakriti/pradhana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/do-non-advaita-vedanta-philosophies-also-believe-that-buddhi-is-part-of-prakriti) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Answered by a user: [Is there a reference to Muslims, Parsis and Christians in Hindu scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24647/is-there-a-reference-to-muslims-parsis-and-christians-in-hindu-scripture) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Good sensitivity Qn: [Is it sinful to look at any women with lustful eyes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/is-it-sinful-to-look-at-any-women-with-lustful-eyes)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Good comparative Qn: [Why do some people see Sankhya as the highest truth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24804/1049)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Qn is a good duplicate link [where in Shiva purana, it is mentioned that "Shiva" is formless God, and "Shankara" is the form which dwells in Mount Kailsha [duplicate]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26197/where-in-shiva-purana-it-is-mentioned-that-shiva-is-formless-god-and-shanka) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- A good duplicate: [If Karna was killed by unethical means, How did Mahabharata yuddham (Mahabharata war) become "Dharma yuddham"(Righteous war)? [duplicate]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26764/1049) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- A Google-able link: [What is the story of Lord Krishna's Panchajanya conch?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27591/1049) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- A harmless duplicate link question: [Why God Shiva used trident on Kashyapa's son? and why could not he save his own son (Ganesha) from curse?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28339/1049)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Deleted due to answer received: [Did Ikshvaku king Anaranya curse Ravana? What are the details of this story?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28361/did-ikshvaku-king-anaranya-curse-ravana-what-are-the-details-of-this-story)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- Edited eversion is good; also it's answered: [Is it possible for a boy from "Pillai" caste to marry a girl from "Vannar"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28056/1049)
- Good duplicate with specific title than original: [Is there a concept of demonic possession in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28484/1049) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

- A good meta Qn, which is **deleted by Community user**. [Where are the veteran users, who used to be good contributors?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/where-are-the-veteran-users-who-used-to-be-good-contributors) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).
  (I have a suggestion to be written as an answer)

Comment: Where to find such deleted questions' links? I mean how do u know these questions were deleted? Also how do u know that these questions were self deleted and not deleted by mods? and final question can the self deleted questions be restored by mods? i know that they can not do so for self deleted comments..

Comment: @Rickross, the deleted Qn-s cannot be found, once lost. An easy way is to flag it or share that link within your email/clipboard etc. If you see the deleted Qn from the PC browser then, it shows that who deleted it. Moderators can restore the self deleted Qn-s, but usually they are very conservative in it. I have got too many flags rejected few weeks back, that I was automatically banned from flagging at all for few days.

Comment: Oh but if i can not even find the links then how to flag.. that's what i was thinking. @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross, yes. Even an OP also can't find link if the post is deleted. At least you can vote in above 2 links to help us undelete the Qn-s. 1 has an answer by you and another has an answer by me.

Comment: Yes i can see that one Q has my answer.. but i don't think it's ok for me to flag because it's OP's right to delete? @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross, don't need to flag. Just **use your undelete vote**. OP should delete in extreme case & this doesn't seem so. Especially when there is an effortful answer.

Comment: Ok.. but if it's not usually allowed, why are they rejecting all ur flags then? @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross Undeleting questions which were deleted by OP is complex job. Some users might delete questions out of embarrassment and some might delete out of fear from downvotes (if their question is bad) and mods will undelete if it is rage-quit. But in other cases, community as whole can undelete them instead of depending on a Mod's sole discretion.  Milind, whenever i reject a flag, i will give reason for rejection.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, yes we had a chat regarding that & you had given reason during then as well. However Few of my flags are rejected without any reason. 1 was just today itself, which I raised for SK-Rickross Qn. I understand that mods may not want to snatch away the privacy part, hence I found this meta way to be feasible.

Comment: Ok @TheDestroyer So, milind i don't think restoration of self deleted posts will be easy to achieve.

Comment: @iammilind BTW i can check which of my answers were deleted recently from this link :https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4732 u must be able to do the same i guess?

Comment: I mean that from that link in my profile i can get the link of a deleted post where i have an answer.. @iammilind i have checked ur profile too..but whether u have recently deleted answers or not is something that i can not see..may be u can..

Comment: @Rickross, yes that seems to be a good link. I can see 2 of my recently deleted wiki answers. Worth updating in Qn

Comment: @iammilind Off-topic questions should be deleted. It is what happens after some days. On many sites, users vote to delete off-topic questions. That question about gems is off-topic and casting an undelete vote on it is not needed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, actually I wouldn't have put for undelete. But it appeared that SwiftPushkar had some important info. Usually closed & downvotrd Qn anyways are deleted by Community. Anyways, I have now removed that Qn.

Comment: Though had quality, this should not have been deleted: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26942/how-did-the-supreme-court-settle-the-varna-jati-guna-argument-on-caste

Comment: I would not undelete the recent question about Pillai caste because it an advice question and asking for help in personal issue. That exactly matches off-topic reason. It's something which should be discussed in the family. Their main question was confirming whether it will be agreed by other family. If we are removing it for our site and answer, it will help the OP in no way because that's not the OP wants to know. Adding answers and undeletion of such advice question would only get users rep but that wouldn't solve OP's problem at all. I would leave it as it's not a great question.

Comment: A question is personal advice and off-topic not only when it has personal details and asked in first person. It will be still off-topic when asked from third person perspective and asking for help in personal life issues. [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/5212). Answers given by us will not be helpful in this matter to the OP. That shouldn't have answered at first place. Having an answer should not be a reason for undeleting an off-topic question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, sometimes first timers don't have clue about titbits of how the SE network works. Usually I tend to give them a 2nd chance. In this case, as users suggested in comment section, the "personal advise" part is removed. IMO, this answer can be objectively answered. However, I understand your points as well. I regard that in this case, we have different views. Which is just fine.

Comment: There are still personal advice questions in the Q. If we answer the question objectively, it helps our reputation levels but not the OP. We answer from ancient smriti texts where Sudhra is different from today's backward classes. The question mainly was asking for girl's family permission. That was his personal life which should be solved by him.He isn't a newbie because he has posted some Q's on other site. He has asked for apples, but we only give oranges. So, it is like forcibly giving oranges even when he doesn't want them. We should answer what OP wants and not what we can.